# How storage markers and center map in Google maps api

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, laravel-5

I written a form within a web page to create a marker for google maps and for center the map, but when i refresh the browser i lose all changes. What solution I could take to make persistent changes?(I don't like cookie).
Sorry for my english.I'll wait for an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  html5 web storage  (all javascript)

With local storage, web applications can store data locally within the user's browser.

Local storage is more secure then cookies, a  large number of data can be easily  stored locally, without affecting, sustantially website performance.

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lat",yourLat);
localStorage.setItem("lng",yourLng);
// Retrieve
myLat  = localStorage.getItem("lat"); 
myLat  = localStorage.getItem("lng");
```

or you can do server side with ajax

See this for more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was very useful.